# How to pass enter text in running cell in google colaboratory?

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I need to push a file to my github repository. But when I run the command -

!git push -u origin master

It asks for my username and password. How Can I enter text (i.e my username and password) to the current running cell?

Comment: Title dose not subup the question.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

- set up an alternate auth mechanism (eg [SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/))
- You can stitch this together with `echo`, something like

  ```
  import getpass
  username = input('Enter username:')
  print('Enter password:')
  password = getpass.getpass()
  !echo '{username}\n{password}\n' | git clone ...
  ```